# Deriving Euler-Lagrange equation for vector field in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I'm trying to derive covariant Euler-Lagrange equations for a vector field. The variation of the action should be

\begin{gather*}
\delta S
=
\int
\text{d}^n{x} \sqrt{|g|}
\left(
\delta\phi^\mu \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial\phi^\mu}
+
\delta\nabla_\alpha\phi^\mu \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)}
\right)
\end{gather*}

and since only the field varies $[\delta,\nabla_\alpha]=0$. I now want

- an element $\delta\phi^\mu \nabla_\alpha (\partial\mathscr{L}/\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu))$ to appear
- a surface term to appear

So I investigated the following promising term

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}
\partial_\alpha
\left( \sqrt{|g|} \delta \phi^\mu \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)} \right)
$$

trying to see if it appears the element inside the expression of the action variation, and in fact it does, because I obtain

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}
\partial_\alpha
\left( \sqrt{|g|} \delta \phi^\mu \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{(\partial\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)} \right)
=
\nabla_\alpha\delta \phi^\mu
\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)}
-
{\Gamma^\mu}_{\nu\alpha} \delta\phi^\nu \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)}
+
\delta\phi^\mu \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)} 
$$

and the first term in the second member is what I was waiting to appear. it is almost perfect if it wasn't for

$$
-
{\Gamma^\mu}_{\nu\alpha} \delta\phi^\nu \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)}
$$

which I have no idea how to eliminate or to absorb in the surface term, that will be discarded with boundary conditions.

Here the detail of the calculation

\begin{multline*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}
\partial_\alpha
\left( \sqrt{|g|} \delta \phi^\mu \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)} \right)
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}
\partial_\alpha \sqrt{|g|}
\,\delta \phi^\mu \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)}
\\
+
\left( \partial_\alpha\delta \phi^\mu + {\Gamma^\mu}_{\nu\alpha} \delta\phi^\nu - {\Gamma^\mu}_{\nu\alpha} \delta\phi^\nu \right)
\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)}
\\
+
\delta\phi^\mu 
\left( \partial_\alpha\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)} + {\Gamma^\alpha}_{\gamma\alpha} \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)} - \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)} \right)
\end{multline*}

\begin{multline*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}
\partial_\alpha
\left( \sqrt{|g|} \delta \phi^\mu \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)} \right)
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}
\partial_\alpha \sqrt{|g|}
\,\delta \phi^\mu \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)}
\\
+
\nabla_\alpha\delta \phi^\mu
\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)} 
-
{\Gamma^\mu}_{\nu\alpha} \delta\phi^\nu \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)}
\\
+
\delta\phi^\mu \nabla_\alpha\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)}
-
\delta\phi^\mu {\Gamma^\alpha}_{\gamma\alpha} \frac{\partial\mathscr{L}}{\partial(\nabla_\alpha \phi^\mu)}
\end{multline*}

and since I'm considering a torsionless manifold ${\Gamma^\alpha}_{\gamma\alpha}={\Gamma^\alpha}_{\alpha\gamma}=\partial_\gamma\ln{|g|}/2$ and the first and last terms in the second member cancel, leaving the result written above.

Is there something wrong with the calculation or the problem is of another kind?